# Footer tag defies assigned behavior

Tags: html, css

The basic layout is

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav></nav>
        <myContent></myContent>
    </div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
```

Where the footer should drop below the body and not be affected by the CSS of the body or its children.

I aim for the footer to be at the bottom of the page no matter how much or how little content the body contains. This CSS should do the trick:

```
    body, html {
        height: 100vh;
        }
    .wrapper {
        min-height: 96vh;
        position: relative;
        }
    footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4vh;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        font-size: .75em;
        }
```

On inspection in my browser, the footer is contained within the body tag. This makes no sense. In addition, the footer shows its width to be the same as the viewport but does not reflect that in the demo model. Instead its left border is on the left side of the page and has about 10% `vw` worth of whitepace to the right. Setting `backround-color: yellow` confirms this. And finally, the position fails to go to the bottom unless `<myContent>` pushes it below the screen's view.

What's wrong with this set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5, most everything that is not specifically in a `<head>` or `<body>` element, whether you actually declare it so or not, gets assigned to whichever is appropriate. If the necessary element doesn't exist, it's created.

As per [the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` are optional. Most browsers work by creating missing elements as necessary. (In my experience, mostly noticed with tables and `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.)

Note that the code you see by using the browser's inspector is usually the code that the browser is working with after "fixing" what it got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the body tag encloses the visible elements of the page. HTML has a HEAD element, but that element is not for visible content, it is for non-visible elements such as links to stylesheets, etc. Your FOOTER element rightly belongs in the BODY element.

Answer (score 0):

footer header and other specific semantic tag must be enclosed to body => http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that having elements outside of the body is not valid HTML. Modern browsers will correct for this and move this elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above notes regarding footer/body placement. Last I read one could place the footer either inside or outside the body, but your comments have been noted.

My footer was misbehaving because the inspector zoom on the index page was changed, but not for any other pages. I don't how that happened, but resetting put it where it needed to be.